# Adding a condition in a LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq

I've a C# statement as follows:

```
var errors =  errorList.Select((e, i) => string.Format("Error occured #{0}: {1} (Error code = {2}).", i + 1, e.Message, e.ErrorCode)).ToArray();
```

I need to display "Error occured" when e.ErrorCode is 'Error' and "Warning occured" when e.ErrorCode is 'Warning'.
How do I add this condition to the above statement please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably just wrap the slightly more complex logic into another method like so..

```
        private string GetErrorCodeLogLabel(ErrorCode code)
        {
            if(code == ErrorCode.Error /* || .. other errors*/)
                return "Error";
            else if (code == ErrorCode.Warning /* || .. other warnings*/)
                return "Warning";

            throw new NotImplementedException(code);
        }

        var errors = errorList.
            Select((e, i) => string.Format("{0} occured #{1}: {2} (Error code = {3}).", GetErrorCodeLogLabel(e.ErrorCode), i + 1, e.Message, e.ErrorCode)).
            ToArray();
```

Comment: I was thinking if we could achieve this without adding a new function.But this works anyway.Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Couldn't you just do this:

```
errorList.Select((e, i) => string.Format("{2} Occured #{0}: {1} (Error code = {2}).", i + 1, e.Message, e.ErrorCode)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks...but the e.ErrorCode enum has other values and I want to display only custom message...ie Error/Warning...  NotImplemented = 0,
        NoDataFound = 1,
        DataAccessError = 2,
        WebServiceError = 3,

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline if: (you may modify the conditions)

```
    var errors = errorList.Select((e, i) => string.Format("{0} occured #{1}: {2} (Error code = {3}).", 
                 e.ErrorCode == ErrorCode.Error ? "Error" : "Warning",
                 i + 1, 
                 e.Message, 
                 e.ErrorCode)).ToArray();
```